# Why preg_replace() function isn't working properly?

Tags: preg-replace

**My PHP Script is:**

```
<?php
    $string = '{controller}/{action}';
    $pattern = '/\{([a-z]+)\}/i';
    $replacement = '(?P<$1>[a-z-]+)';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

**it is showing this result:**

```
(?P[a-z-]+)\/(?P[a-z-]+)
```

**I am expecting this:**

```
(?P<controller>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<action>[a-z-]+)
```

How I can able to do this??

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem: https://3v4l.org/7UJnJ

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces the correct result, that is,

```
(?P<controller>[a-z-]+)\/(?P<action>[a-z-]+)
```

The problem is: when you `echo` that out and display it in a browser, the browser interprets `<controller>` and `<action>` as HTML tags, like `<p>` or `<strong>`. So, it doesn't display them; it only displays what is left:

```
(?P[a-z-]+)\/(?P[a-z-]+)
```

You would see the correct result if you ran this script from the command line. To make it work in the browser, you need to replace the last line with

```
echo htmlentities(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string));
```